# Floating input icon in PlatformTextFormField isn't behaving properly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

The widget is from the package 'flutter_platform_widgets'

As you can see, the floating icon that shows input location doesn't go behind app bar when screen is scrolled down. I need to either get rid of it completely or at least have it disappear properly. I tried dismissing the keyboard on screen drag, but it gets a bit annoying as all the content fits on one screen, it isn't actually scrollable (scrollview necessary because there is content behind the keyboard and I was getting pixel overflow errors without it).

[image]

[image]

Some code if that helps

[image]

EDIT:

This is the widget seen on the first two screenshots.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
      child: Form(
        key: widget.formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          // keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              EmailTextFormField(
                controller: widget.emailController,
              ),
              PasswordTextFormField(
                labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.password,
                controller: widget.passwordController,
              ),
              PasswordTextFormField(
                labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.confirmPassword,
                controller: widget.passwordConfirmationController,
                password: widget.passwordController,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: Button(
                  text: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.next,
                  onPressed: () {
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    _validateLoginInformation();
                  },
                ),
              ),

              ,
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.75,
              ),
              const TermsOfUse(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the emailtextformfield. The code for passwordtextformfield is nearly identical.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.mail_outline,
            color: iconColor,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: AutofillGroup(
            child: PlatformTextFormField(
              hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.email,
              controller: widget.controller,
              focusNode: _focusNode,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.email],
              onFieldSubmitted: (_) => _focusNode.nextFocus(),
              validator: (email) {
                if (email == null || email.isEmpty) {
                  return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.emailIsNull;
                } else if (!EmailValidator.validate(email)) {
                  return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.emailInvalid;
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              },
              material: (_, __) => MaterialTextFormFieldData(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                  labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.email,
                  suffixIcon: widget.controller.text.isNotEmpty
                      ? ClearTextFieldIcon(controller: widget.controller)
                      : null,
                ),
              ),
              cupertino: (_, __) => CupertinoTextFormFieldData(
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                focusNode: _focusNode,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: CupertinoColors.extraLightBackgroundGray,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide some code instead of a screenshot to reproduce the issue fastly?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to remove it. But you can make it `invisible` by setting its color to `transparent`.

You can set the color `globally`:

```
textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(
              selectionHandleColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
```

`main.dart`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(
          selectionHandleColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
```

I also tried to set it `locally` using the `Theme` widget, but it seems buggy.

You can also access the complete source code through [GitHub](https://github.com/BBarisKilic/Stack-OverFlow-Solutions/tree/master/question_72537235).

If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to write in the comments.